# string constructor taking two char* into another std::string works in c++14 but not c++17

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

The following program attempts to construct a second string using the first string and a pointer into the middle of the first string:

```
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string src = "hello world";
  const char* end = &src[5];
  std::string dest(src.data(), end);
}
```

In C++14 and earlier this works. But [in C++17 the call fails](https://wandbox.org/permlink/fQIbQ2PdJ55AUk5F):

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>::basic_string(char*, const char*&)’
   std::string dest(src.data(), end);
[... full output omitted ...]
```

What changed to make this fail?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The construction of `dest` is attempting to use the following constructor (from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string)):

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

This requires that `first` and `last` have the exact same type. The problem is that in [C++17 `std::string::data` returns a *non-const* pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) when called on a non-const `std::string`. This means the type of `first` is `char*` and the type of `last` is `const char*`. Since they differ, the template argument `InputIt` cannot be deduced and the call fails.

There is no way to explicitly specify the template argument to a constructor call, but there is a solution. [`std::string::c_str` still returns a `const char*`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) and the construction of `dest` can use it:

```
std::string dest(src.c_str(), end);
```

Another solution would be calling `data()` on a `str` through a const reference:

```
const auto& const_src = src;
std::string dest(const_src.data(), end);
```

Or if you don't care about C++14 compatability you can use `std::as_const` (thanks Mário Feroldi)

```
std::string dest(std::as_const(src).data(), end);
```

Comment: Another possibility is to just get rid of the `end` pointer altogether: `const char* start = src.c_str(); std::string dest(start, start+5);`  Or: `char* start = src.data(); std::string dest(start, start+5);`  Or, just use a different constructor, like: `std::string dest(src.c_str(), 5);`

Comment: You can use C++17's [`std::as_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const) to call the const version of `data()`.

Comment: I think proper solution is to define `end` as an iterator `auto end = std::next( src.begin(), 5 );` and not to use pesky pointers

Comment: @zett42 not in this case, as there is `std::string::iterator` and it is not equal to pointer

Comment: also `std::string dest(&src[0], end);` -- matching the same method of generating iterator for both arguments

Comment: @Slava A pointer is *always* an iterator, that doesn't change on case-by-case basis. In OPs question, the only issue is that the *type* of begin and end iterator is different (const vs. non-const).

Comment: @zett42 I do not want to argue, but if OP would use `std::begin() + 5` and `std::begin()` code would work c++11 and later.

Comment: @Slava Sure, as would `std::string::data() + 5` and `std::string::data()`.

Comment: If the code is to be converted to C++17 anyway, then the OP might consider turning `dest` into a `std::string_view`.

Comment: Are we just listing alternatives? Count me in `src.substr(0, 5)`

Comment: @Barry `std::string dest{"hello"};` and you don't even need a `src`!